# HTML/CSS social media icons are huge in WordPress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, image, social-networking

I am trying to add social media buttons to my WordPress page via HTML code:

[image]

However, they styling does not work, they take up the entire page and are much too big. Why does this happen, and can I fix it?

Here is the code:

```
<style type="text/css">

#share-buttons img {
width: 35px;
padding: 5px;
border: 0;
box-shadow: 0;
display: inline;
}

</style>

<div id="share-buttons">

<!-- Facebook -->
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://www.jusskaur.com/blog/workshop-with-senior-ladies/" target="_blank">
<img src="http://www.jusskaur.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/facebook.png" width="35" height="35" alt="Facebook" />
</a>

<!-- Twitter -->
<a href="https://twitter.com/share?url=http://www.jusskaur.com/blog/workshop-with-senior-ladies/&amp;text=Simple%20Share%20Buttons&amp;hashtags=simplesharebuttons" target="_blank">
<img src="http://www.jusskaur.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/twitter.png" alt="Twitter" />
</a>

<!-- Google+ -->
<a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=http://www.jusskaur.com/blog/workshop-with-senior-ladies/" target="_blank">
<img src="http://www.jusskaur.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/google.png" alt="Google" />
</a>

<!-- LinkedIn -->
<a href="http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&amp;url=http://www.jusskaur.com/blog/workshop-with-senior-ladies/" target="_blank">
<img src="http://www.jusskaur.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/linkedin.png" alt="LinkedIn" />
</a>

<!-- Pinterest -->
<a>
<img src="http://www.jusskaur.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/pinterest.png" alt="Pinterest" />
</a>

<!-- Email -->
<a href="mailto:?Subject=Simple Share Buttons&amp;Body=I%20saw%20this%20and%20thought%20of%20you!%20 https://simplesharebuttons.com">
<img src="http://www.jusskaur.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/email.png" alt="Email" />
</a>

</div>
```

Comment: If you do "Inspect Element" can you confirm that the styles are being applied? [I can't reproduce it.](https://jsfiddle.net/3wegh38u/)

Comment: They aren't – this applies: #content-container img {
    width: 100%;
} but the css I wanted to use isn't being applied for some reason

Comment: please try #share-buttons img {
width: 35px!important;
padding: 5px;
border: 0;
box-shadow: 0;
display: inline;
}

Comment: @user3034357 That selector is identical in form to yours, so if it is later in the HTML/CSS, it gets priority.

Answer (score 2):

When a style is being overwritten by another style, the best fix is to use a stronger selector:

```
#share-buttons a img { /* added 'a' */
    width: 35px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: 0;
    display: inline;
}
```

For a more in-depth explanation of CSS specificity, read [this CSS Tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/).

Answer (score 0):

instead, define a specific size for the 'a' tags and set the images to be 100% width.

```
#share-buttons a { width:35px, display:inline-block}
#share-buttons a img {width: 100%}
```

also, remove the width parameter in the 'a' tags

Answer (score 0):

Add this,

```
#share-buttons {
width: 100%;
height:auto;
padding: 5px;
border: 0;
box-shadow: 0;
display: inline;
}
#share-buttons > a{
  text-decoration:none;
}
#share-buttons > a > img{
  width:35px;
  height:35px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#share-buttons img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

#share-buttons a {
    width: 35px !important;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: `!Important` should rarely be used. Many would say **NEVER** : https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/